# HTML Email : make fonts lighter

Tags: html, css

I want to make fonts lighter as displayed in image.

[image: Here is the image]

```html
<table width="600" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" style="background-image: url(http://www.hubilo.com/eventApp/ws/images/event/cover/facebook/thumb/2712_1467715620.jpg); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; -webkit-background-size: cover; border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt; width: 100%; ">
  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td valign="top" align="center" height="80"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="h2" valign="top" align="center" style="color: white; text-align: center; text-transform: uppercase; font-weight:100 !important; letter-spacing: 12px; font-size: 32px; ">
        <p>TIECON</p>
      </td>
    </tr>


  </tbody>

</table>
```

After my effort , I get different result which is in snippet.

Thank You.

Comment: use a image not text

Comment: but there might be different texts as per different scenario , so  it is not useful .

Comment: I would settle for a more standard font. HTML Emails need to be compatible with as many devices, and clients as possible. So try to stick to default fonts to use. Ultimately, if you really need the desired look for branding, I would suggest using an image as mentioned.

Comment: exactly... agree with you. but there is a need to do so , that's why i have to give output according to need. otherwise i use standard fonts which supports almost all kind of devices and Email clients.

Comment: Can you write a backend service that returns an dynamically generated image (with caching obviously). E.g. your email image reference could point at `https://www.example.com/text.png?text=TIECON`.

Comment: that was the question in my mind , and I asked to my Team Leader. He said , will do in future. otherwise there would have not been any issue regarding the same. :)

Comment: as I am responsible for Front end Part, so can't interfere with Backend stuffs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [Google fonts API](https://developers.google.com/fonts/).

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Open Sans'), local('OpenSans'), url('http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/opensans/v5/cJZKeOuBrn4kERxqtaUH3T8E0i7KZn-EPnyo3HZu7kw.woff') format('woff');
}
#lightfont {
  font-family: 'open sans', arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700&amp;subset=latin" rel="stylesheet">

<table width="600" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" style="background-image: url(http://www.hubilo.com/eventApp/ws/images/event/cover/facebook/thumb/2712_1467715620.jpg); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; -webkit-background-size: cover; border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt; width: 100%; ">
  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td valign="top" align="center" height="80"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="h2" valign="top" align="center" style="color: white; text-align: center; text-transform: uppercase; font-weight:100 !important; letter-spacing: 12px; font-size: 32px; ">
        <p id="lightfont">TIECON</p>
      </td>
    </tr>


  </tbody>

</table>
```